# how do I restart ghost on an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, npm, ghost-blog

I have Ghost running on an EC2 instance and I'd like to restart it after making changes to the source.

I CD'd into the ghost directory and ran the following command

```
sudo npm restart
```

I get the following errors

```
> ghost@0.4.2 start /var/www/ghost
> node index


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at net.js:1146:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
    at process._tickFromSpinner (node.js:390:15)

npm ERR! ghost@0.4.2 start: `node index`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ghost@0.4.2 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ghost package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ghost
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.48-55.140.amzn1.i686
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "restart"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/ghost
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/ghost/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

All I've really done is added a them to the themes folder and it's not showing up in the admin settings and I figured restarting ghost would help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use [these](http://howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-setup-an-amazon-ec2-instance-to-host-ghost-for-free/) instructions?  If so you can restart Ghost with:

```
pm2 restart ghost
```

In that command ghost is the name of the pm2 process which you can get from

```
pm2 list
```

Comment: Make sure you are logged in as the ghost user if OP is having problems

Answer (score 0):

When I received the same error message, I had a node instance running on the same port. Search for the process by `sudo ps aux | grep node` and kill that node process if possible.